# Beginning PHP (loading DIV)

Tags: php

I'm just diving into PHP and have been doing some reading and playing around - with my code below, I'm trying to load the pages (as you can see) - I'm getting parse error. Syntax error, unexpecter T_VARIABLE in index.php on line 7

Line 7 on my index

```
<?php include(''$id'') ?>
```

I'm told is supposed to be for variables rather than ('$id')

When I use ('$id') or ('$nav_menu') as is in the current coding, it gives me failed to open stream: No such file or directory

I'm probably missing something blatantly obvious, but can someone point me in the right direction?

Thanks

```
<?php
if (is_numeric($_GET['id'])) //prevent hacking
{
switch ($_GET['id']) //get the id of menu needed for this page
{
case 0:
    $nav_menu = "content.php"; //if the variable is 0 or not set
    break;
case 1:
    $nav_menu = "bio.php"; //if the variable is 1, get category 1 links
    break;
case 2:
    $nav_menu = "contact.php"; //if the variable is 2, get category 2 links
    break;
default:
    $nav_menu = "content.php"; //redundant for defaulting if the id is greater than 2
}
}
?>
```

Comment: Btw why do you ever want to use 2 pairs of single quotes around the $id variable?

Comment: @luca When you want to include the file '$id.php' ? :D It probably works on a Mac!

Comment: @frits van Campen Yeah! you're right (I tried it works =D)

Comment: Awesome! :D +1 for actually trying

Answer (score 4):

```
<?php include($id); ?>
```

no quotes.

Also, make sure you check the value of $id, you wouldn't want someone including "../../path/to/my/passwords.txt" or something equally unnerving ;)

The switch-case statement you have for `$nav_menu` is crude but effective and most certainly required.

Also, I'm pretty sure `switch` is safe so no need to check `is_numeric` on `$_GET['id']`

Edit: Jared mentioned relative vs absolute paths. I have no idea what he's saying but this is what I think about it:
Always always always always always always always always always always always always always always always always always always always always always always always always always use:

```
include (dirname(__FILE__) . "/thefile.ext");
```

this will always make your path without a doubt *absolute*.

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to use quotes around a variable, but if you do, make sure you use `"` instead of `''`. You could try:

```
<?php
include($id);
include($nav_menu);
?>
```

17 lines code could be shortened into two. You could use it instead:

```
<?php
$list = array("content.php", "bio.php", "contact.php");
$navmenu = (isset($_GET['id']) && isset($list[$_GET['id']]) ? $list[$_GET['id']] : 'content.php';
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You're doing four things wrong here.

First, you need semicolons at the end of each statement.

```
<?php include(''$id''); ?> // Note semicolon
```

You should have only one quote on either end of an inline string statement, with the other's escaped, ie:

```
<?php include('\'$id\''); ?> // Valid string
```

Now, if you want to expand that variable, you need to either use a double-quoted string or use a `.` concatenator. In this case, you don't need a quote around it:

```
<?php include("$id"); ?>
<?php include($id); ?>
```

Last, you should be giving the relative/absolute path to a file to include.

```
<?php

$path = "myinclude.php";
$path = "../includes/myinclude.php";
$path = "/web/my_site_com/includes/myinclude.php";

include($path);

?>
```

If you're using the switch to activate a particular file, you could do this with a double-quoted string:

```
<?php

$path = "../includes/$id";

include($path);

?>
```